# What is the advantage of the staticmethod decorator?

Tags: python

(Note: I have seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059968/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-staticmethods), and my question is effectively a follow-up to it).

Suppose we have the following class:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def decorated_sum(a, b):
        return a + b
    
    def undecorated_sum(a, b):
        return a + b
```

Both of the following are valid, and the syntax is identical, so what is the advantage of the decorated method?

```
A.decorated_sum(1, 2)    # 3
A.undecorated_sum(1, 2)  # 3
```

Is it literally just to stop people from doing the following by mistake?

```
A().undecorated_sum(1, 2) # error: undecorated_sum takes two args but was given three (including self).
```

Comment: Many argue that a `staticmethod` should really just be a function. But well, sometimes it makes sense to have a method which needs neither `self` nor `cls` and may be called either way, so that’s what it’s for.

Comment: It's to *allow* people to do `some_class_instance.some_static_method()` instead of `SomeClass.some_static_method()`. But I'll be frank, I think I've used a `staticmethod` in production maybe once or twice, and at least one time it was because I was too lazy to change an already existing import